# PowerShell Array w/ Filter ~ ParameterBindingException

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to make a list of users and compare their SamAccount Names to Active Directory and to filter which user AD accounts are disabled.

I receive the error message below when I execute the script.

I do the following:

```
$Names = @("Shannon.Hoffman","Kameron.Mack","Ashleigh.Reeves","Diego.Colon","Mayra Ortega","Mark.Dunn")
Get-ADUser -Filter {(Enabled -eq "False") -and (SAMAccountName -like $Names)}
```

I recieve this error message:

```
Get-ADUser : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser' required by parameter 'Identity'. Specified method is not supported.
```

I also get an error saying `ParameterBindingException`

I am relatively new to PowerShell. Can you please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would really suggest that you learn PowerShell before trying to do useful things. Things can go badly very quickly.

For one thing, you are filtering using the entire list instead of per user, so you would need to use a loop. Something like the below could do what you require:

```
$Names = @("username1","username2")
Foreach ($Name in $Names){
    $User = Get-ADUser -Identity $Name
    if ($User.Enabled){
        #user is enabled, add to your list
    }
}
```

Heres some extra reading:

[Foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-6)

[Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/understanding-the-powershell-pipeline?view=powershell-6)

[PS AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/?view=win10-ps)

Comment: Thank you very much, this fixed my problem. Thank you for the links, I'm definitely going to do more reading on this, thanks!

Comment: I ended up using this:


```$SAMAccountNames = ("user.name","user.name")
    foreach ($SAMAccountName in $SAMAccountNames)
    {
        Get-ADUser -Filter {(SamAccountName -eq $SAMAccountName) -and (Enabled -eq "False")} #Finds the disabled accounts from the list
    }```

Comment: You could just use if (!$User.IsEnabled) from my example to get the disabled users. What you're doing is getting an entire list of your domain users every time just to find one user. This isn't good coding, to be honest.